# Typescript not enforcing interface when assigning result of Object.assign

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces;

```
interface ComponentInterface {
    pollution: number,
    funds: number
}

interface ConfigInterface {
    pollution?: number,
    funds?: number
}
```

And then I have a function that creates objects based on the interfaces;

```
function create(oConfig: ConfigInterface = {}): ComponentInterface {
    // Merge the config with component defaults
    const oComponent: ComponentInterface = Object.assign({
        pollution: 0
    }, oConfig);

    // ...
}
```

And I'm calling the function without any arguments like;

```
create();
```

I don't understand why my compiler isn't throwing an error here. AFAIK I'm assigning **{ pollution: 0 }** to a variable that's expecting a ComponentInterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is working well.
[It does complain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ComponentInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pollution%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funds%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ConfigInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pollution%3F%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funds%3F%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create(oConfig%3A%20ConfigInterface%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%3A%20ComponentInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Merge%20the%20config%20with%20component%20defaults%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20oComponent%3A%20ComponentInterface%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pollution%3A%200%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20oConfig)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%7D) saying:

> Type '{ pollution: number; } & ConfigInterface' is not assignable to
>   type 'ComponentInterface'.
>   Property 'funds' is optional in type '{
>   pollution: number; } & ConfigInterface' but required in type
>   'ComponentInterface'.

Which is what you'd expect considering the [signature of the function](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4568):

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
    ...
}
```

Where `T` is `{ pollution: number; }` and `U` is `ConfigInterface`.

Also, You can also use `Partial` instead of redefining all props:

```
type ConfigInterface = Partial<ComponentInterface>;
```

Comment: I had the same.

Comment: I looks at though it's just my compiler that isn't flagging it then! (atom-typescript 11.0.3)